# Proof of a fixed point theorem in Hilbert spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading ''class notes on operator theory on hilbert spaces'' by John Petrovic ([http://homepages.wmich.edu/~petrovic/courses/Math6780/m678notesch1.pdf](http://homepages.wmich.edu/%7Epetrovic/courses/Math6780/m678notesch1.pdf)) And in page 53 it proves the following fixed point theorem:

Let $F$ be a compact and convex subset of a Hilbert space $H$, and let $T$ be a linear operator in $\mathcal{L}(H)$ such that $T(F)\subset F$. Then, there exists $p\in H$ such that $T(p)=p$.

I have a question about the proof:

First we define $T_n=\frac{1+T+\dots+T^{n-1}}{n}~\forall~n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then, it claims that $T_n(F)T_m(F)\subset T_n(F)\cap T_m(F)~\forall~n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $\lbrace T_n(F)\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a family satisfying the finite intersection property (i.e every finite intersection of elements of the family is non-empty)

I don't understand why this is true, and in the notes they don't say anything about it. Hope you can help me doing the details.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a typo there, should be $T_n(T_m(F)) \subset T_n(F) \cap T_m(F)$ .  This on the other hand follows from the fact that $T_n(F) \subset F$ for any $n$ (which is proved in the line above), It follows that any finite intersection of $T_{n1}, ...T_{nk}$ is not empty by induction.

Comment: By the way, the fact that intersection of decreasing nested sequences of non-empty compact sets is not empty is called  "Cantor intersection" theorem.

Comment: Technically, you missed the assumption that $F$ is nonempty. This is rather crucial.

Comment: @Salcio Thanks, correcting the typo I am able to prove that $T_n(T_m(F))\subset T_n(F)$ and that the familly satisfies the finite intersection property. Can you help me with the proof of $T_n(T_m(F))\subset T_m(F)$?

Comment: $T_n$ and $T_m$ commute that is $T_n(T_m(F))= T_m(T_n(F))$ - this is just from their definition. Since you know that $T_n(F) \subset F$ you get $T_m(T_n(F) ) \subset T_m(F)$ and since $T_m(F) \subset F$ you get $T_n(T_m(F)) \subset T_n(F)$. In words, intersection of $T_n(F) \cap T_m(F)$ contains $T_m(T_n(F)) = T_n(T_m(F))$ so it is not empty.